# Method for validating request in BaseController in Laravel for APIs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-api

I've been trying to create a method in BaseController.php for validating requests in laravel for APIs. If I use the `$this->validate($request, $rules)` in API controller it doesn't return the required result. I used this code initially.

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
    'phoneNo' => "required|max:15|min:11|unique:users,phoneNo",
    'username' => 'required|unique:users,username',
    'password' => 'required',
    'c_password' => 'required|same:password'
]);
   
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());       
}
```

But I don't want to do this for every method in every controller.
So, I thought that instead of writing this in every controller I should create a method in BaseController.php which I can use in every controller as all controllers are inherited from the BaseController.php.
So, I wrote this to achieve the functionality but this isn't working as it should.

```php
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * success response method.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function sendResponse($result, $message)
    {
        $response = [
            'success' => true,
            'data'    => $result,
            'message' => $message,
        ];

        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }


    /**
     * return error response.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function sendError($error, $errorMessages = [], $code = 404)
    {
        $response = [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $error,
        ];

        if (!empty($errorMessages)) {
            $response['data'] = $errorMessages;
        }

        return response()->json($response, $code);
    }

    public function validateRequest($request, $rules)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) return $this->sendError("Validation Error.", $validator->errors());
    }
}
```

And in the register controller I use this

```php
$this->validateRequest($request, [
     'name' => 'required',
     'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
     'phoneNo' => "required|max:15|min:11|unique:users,phoneNo",
     'username' => 'required|unique:users,username',
     'password' => 'required',
     'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
]);
```

but it doesn't return an exception here. So, I have to add return to this statement in order for it to return an error. but it should stop the process itself and return the response to API here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: just to be sure, you are not mixing up `$request->validate()` and `Validator::make` right? the former throws an exception, the latter gives you `boolean`.

Comment: What you're trying to do exists already https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation you dont need to do it in the BaseController.

Comment: As other user stated, you are literally reinventing the wheel, you just need to use a [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) (please read the documentation as Laravel has everything basic solved!)

Answer (score 1):

## Update

I found the answer to it. I was a little wrong about this. I forgot to add `Accept: "application/json"` parameter in the header. We can simply use the same old validation method:

```
$request->validate([
     'name' => 'required',
     'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
     'phoneNo' => "required|max:15|min:11|unique:users,phoneNo",
     'username' => 'required|unique:users,username',
     'password' => 'required',
     'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
]);
```

If you are working with API and you want to show a JSON response to this then, you can simply add this in your request headers and it will return a proper JSON response:

```
Accept: "application/json"
```